# How to unlock bootloader of Vivo Y33S - 'Waiting for device' error

Tags: bootloader-lock, vivo

I'm facing some challenges with unlocking the bootloader of my Vivo Y33S and could really use some assistance. I have tried a few methods, but I'm encountering two specific issues:

The MTKclient software doesn't seem to work for bootloader unlocking on my Vivo Y33S. I've followed the instructions to enter in Brom mode, but it doesn't recognize my device or initiate the unlock process.

When I use the Vivo Fastboot software and execute the commands `fastboot vivo_bsp unlock_vivo` or `fastboot bbk unlock_vivo`, I receive the following error messages:

```
FAILED (remote: Unrecognized command vivo_bsp unlock_vivo)
FAILED (remote: Unrecognized command bbk unlock_vivo)
```

I have verified that USB debugging and OEM unlocking are enabled on my device. I'm running stock firmware version PD2147GF_EX_A_38.13.0. I've also ensured that I have the latest drivers installed.

Has anyone successfully unlocked the bootloader of the Vivo Y33S? If so, could you please share any alternative methods or potential solutions to overcome these challenges? Your insights and expertise would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: "I've followed the instructions" - how should we know which instruction you followed? Please edit your question and describe in detail what you did and what does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with you, as far as I think, is that you did not [enter the fastboot mode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4FV-V6e2Zmo) on your device. As in the error, `fastboot bbk unlock_vivo` is used to unlock the bootloader.

I'd highly suggest you watch youtube tutorials if you are not really into these stuffs. If you can't find a tutorial regarding the specific model of your phone, watch general videos relevant to the company of your phone.

Comment: I Have entered Fastboot mode, both with the volume buttons, and with `adb reboot fastboot` and `adb reboot bootloader`, But it still doesn't work.

Comment: What do you see on `fastboot devices`. Try unlocking manually using the commands: `fastboot bbk unlock_vivo` and `fastboot bbk vivo_bsp unlock_vivo` https://www.gizdev.com/how-to-unlock-vivo-phones-bootloader-free-methods/

Comment: When i  execute the command `fastboot devices` it shows `3419116439001S1 fastboot` and trying to use `fastboot bbk unlock_vivo` or `fastboot vivo_bsp unlock_vivo` only shows `FAILED (remote: Unrecognized command bbk unlock_vivo)
finished. total time: 0.003s` or `FAILED (remote: Unrecognized command vivo_bsp unlock_vivo)
finished. total time: 0.002s`

Comment: That's odd.. that's what we do for vivos. But anyway do `fastboot flashing unlock`.. should work in my opinion.

Comment: I have tried `fastboot flashing unlock` and `fastboot oem unlock` but they both just give me the error: `FAILED (remote: unknown command)
finished. total time: 0.000s`

Comment: Do `fastboot -help` there should be fewer commands than usual. What is the fastboot version you are using on your pc? Try removing the old version and install adb 1.4.3 from XDA (15 sec installer)

Comment: On the vivo fastboot there are fewer commands, and for normal fastboot i use minimal adb and fastboot